# Calculate complex function $f(z)$ in this condition.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a regular analytic function on $\mathbb C$.

Define $h(r)$ as $$h(r)=\max_{z\in \mathbb C, |z|=r} |f(z)|$$
for $r>0.$

And suppose there exists $M>0$ and $k \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $$h(r)\leqq M r^k \ \mathrm{for \ all} \ r>0.$$

Then, find all possible $f(z).$

---

I think the expansion of $f(z)$ may be useful since the condition that $f$ is regular analytic is given, but as following, my method doesn't seem to work.

Let $C$ be a circle centered on $0$ with radius $r>0$ on complex plain. Then,

\begin{align*}
f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\int_C \dfrac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw\right)z^n.
\end{align*}

And
\begin{align}
|f(z)|
&=\left|\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\int_C \dfrac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw\right)z^n\right|\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi }\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_C \dfrac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw\cdot z^n\right|\\
&\leqq M r^k
\end{align}

---

This doesn't seem to proceed.

I would like you to give me any idea.

Comment: Instead of bounding the entire series at once, try bounding each coefficient individually (using the same Cauchy integral formula). You should find a very strong bound when $n$ is large enough in terms of $k$.

Comment: Letting $a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}\ dw,$I found $a_n=0$ for $n>k.$ But what should I do for $n\leqq k$ ? @GregMartin

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is true if and only if $f(z)=cz^{k}$ for some constant $c$. Taking $r=|z|$ observe that $|f(z)| \leq M|z|^{k}$. This implies that $f$ is polynomial of degree at  most $k$ [A proof of this well known result can easily be found on this site]. Now look at the order of zero of $f$ at $0$ to conclude that its only zero is $0$.